# Length of frames for calculating cepstral coefficients

Tags: audio, sound, cepstral-analysis

For audio classification we are using the cepstral coefficients and their derivatives. Which I calculate using the Matlab libary [voicebox](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/voicebox.html).

I am looking for some literature for how to choose the frame length and overlap of frames. Most literature that I know of are considering speech recognition, but for this application are the audio signals not generated by humans and they are chancing slowly over time. I suppose the last part have an impact when choosing the frame length?